# The multi-part identifier could not be bound, I only get this error when I add another table to the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, inner-join

I am getting this error when trying to get the following resultset

```
SELECT SUM(T3.PURCHQTY) FROM PURCHREQLINE T3, INVENTTABLE T1
                    INNER JOIN PURCHREQTABLE T2 ON T2.RECID = T3.PURCHREQTABLE WHERE (
                        (T3.ITEMID = T1.ITEMID) 
                        AND (T3.ITEMIDDATAAREA = T1.DATAAREAID)
                        AND (T2.REQUISITIONSTATUS <> 40 )
                        AND (T2.REQUISITIONSTATUS <> 50 )
                        AND (T2.REQUISITIONSTATUS <> 20 ));
```

However when I remove T1 and the WHERE Clause it works

```
SELECT SUM(T3.PURCHQTY) FROM PURCHREQLINE T3 INNER JOIN PURCHREQTABLE T2 ON T2.RECID = 
T3.PURCHREQTABLE;
```

UPDATE: im trying to get the sum of every requisition with a designated id, something like this:

```
SELECT T3.PURCHREQTABLE REQ,SUM(T3.PURCHQTY) AS TOTAL FROM PURCHREQLINE T3 INNER JOIN PURCHREQTABLE T2 ON T2.RECID = T3.PURCHREQTABLE GROUP BY PURCHREQTABLE;
```

However I also need the conditions displayed on the WHERE clause above

[image: Here's a picture of the result set]

Comment: What do you meant by it works. Could you please share some sample data.

Comment: Comma means cross join but with lower precedence than keyword JOINs. So the JOIN ON is done first & the left table of the comma is not known there. So don't mix comma with keyword joins.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] If you cut this down to minimal still giving the error it'd be just comma & JOIN you could google it & find it is a SO faq.

Comment: Please don't add EDITs/UPDATEs, edit the the best possible presentation that does not invalidate reasonable posted answers. Ask about code you can't understand separately from your overall goal. Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why. Then if you again get stuck getting to your overall goal that's a separate question to post.Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 3):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

So:

```
SELECT SUM(PR.PURCHQTY)
FROM PURCHREQLINE PR INNER JOIN
     INVENTTABLE I
     ON PR.ITEMID = I.ITEMID AND 
        PR.ITEMIDDATAAREA = I.DATAAREAID INNER JOIN
     PURCHREQTABLE PRT
     ON PRT.RECID = PR.PURCHREQTABLE
WHERE PRT.REQUISITIONSTATUS NOT IN (20, 40, 50);
```

Note the changes to the query:

- The table aliases are abbreviations for the column names, so they make sense when reading them.
- The repeated `<>` comparisons are more concisely written using `NOT IN`.
- There are no commas in the `FROM` clause.

Also:  It is not worth explaining *why* your query generates an error (the scoping rules for commas are different from `JOIN`), because you simply should never be using that construct.  It has been obsolete for decades.